# Issue Devmode is still enable in multi-environment config file

Tags: devmode

I have an issue with a site I have just put live. devMode is still enabled even though the config site sets it as false for .com.

Code snippet:

```
'*' => array(
        'devMode' => 'false',
        'siteName' => 'sitename',
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
        'maxUploadFileSize' => 33554432,
        'defaultSearchTermOptions' => array(
            'subLeft' => true,
            'subRight' => true,
        ),
        ),
    '.com' => array(
        'devMode' => 'false',
        'env' => 'live',
```

I did have a .dev option as well but removed this to see if it would make any difference but it hasn't.

Next I cleared all caches and still no joy devMode is still active. How can I clear this for the the live site has it logged it in the DB somewhere and it's not removing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re setting the `devMode` setting to the string `'false'`, which seems to be evaluated to true. You need to set it to a boolean.

```
'*' => array(
    'devMode' => false,
),
'.dev' => array(
    'devMode' => true,
),
```

Comment: Ah ha. Good spot carl. Will remove quotes and re-upload. School boy error!!

Answer (score 1):

The ordersequence of the environements does matter.

```
return array(
  '*' => array(
    //yadayadayada
  ),
  // this has priority over the lower entry
  '.com' => array(
    'devMode' => true,
  ),
  // this has even lower priority
  '.dev' => array(
    'devMode' => false,
   ),
);
```

Comment: Or was it vice versa? Now I'm not sure.

Comment: No, you are right with priority. But settings in the array with the key `'*'` are overridden by the (matching) ones in the other keys.

Comment: Both are set to false though!